# How to use TypeToken to get type parameter?

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am attempting to look up a type parameter at runtime using `TypeToken` as showing in the [Guava documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) example `IKnowMyType`:

```
public class Test<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private static enum MyEnum {
        FIRST,
        SECOND
    };

    private final TypeToken<E> enumType = new TypeToken<E>(getClass()) {
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<MyEnum> container = new Test<>();
        System.out.println(container.enumType.getRawType());
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get `class java.lang.Enum` as output. Why am not not getting `class MyEnum` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This "hack" won't work on a value of runtime type `Test`.

There's no way for Java to propagate the type argument inferred when instantiating your `Test` class here

```
Test<MyEnum> container = new Test<>();
```

down to the declaration

```
private final TypeToken<E> enumType = new TypeToken<E>(getClass()) {
};
```

And therefore the `TypeToken` has no idea what the `E` should refer to.

The [Javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken(java.lang.Class)) states

> Constructs a new type token of `T` while resolving free type variables
>   **in the context of `declaringClass`**.
>
> **Clients create an empty anonymous subclass.** Doing so embeds the type
>   parameter in the anonymous class's type hierarchy so we can
>   reconstitute it at runtime despite erasure.

So that's what you need to do.

```
Test<MyEnum> container = new Test<MyEnum>() {
};
```

Now, because classes maintain information about their generic superclasses, the `getClass` call in the `TypeToken` instantiation above provides enough context for the `E` to be interpreted as `MyEnum`.

Comment: I don't understand. What does `Sample` refer to in your answer? Are you saying that I must create a subclass `Sample extends Test` and then I will be able to look up `Sample.enumType`?

Comment: @Gili Sorry, I was using my own test class. `Sample` is your `Test`. You create an anonymous subclass of `Test`, yes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you please explain some more what the `{}` exactly does. Can you show some other example where the `{}` is used.

Comment: @KevinWallis That's the syntax for anonymous classes. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) the official tutorial.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ahh `TypeToken` is `abstract` so i understand. I was thinking why you create an `anonymous` class

Comment: @KevinWallis [Here's](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) more information about how type tokens work.

Comment: Beware! This technique stops working if you use factory methods: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38047417/14731